# Reduced mod $p$ homology of a $p$-complete Eilenberg-MacLane space

Tags: homology-cohomology, eilenberg-maclane-spaces

Let $A$ be a $p$-complete abelian group for some prime $p$. Is it true that $\tilde{H}_*(K(A,2);\mathbb{F}_p)=0$? If so, how can one prove it?

Please, also let me know if this hold only if we require other properties from $A$!

Comment: This is not true.  If $A = \mathbb{F}_p$, then at the very least you will have the fundamental class in $H_2(K(\mathbb{F}_p, 2); \mathbb{F}_p)$.

Comment: If you post that as an answer, I will accept it!